# How to retrieve a US DS-160 confirmation page?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork, applications

I completed a DS160 online application form for the US embassy in Barbados.  I got a confirmation page, but it was not printed legibly. I do not have the application ID. Can I retrieve the confirmation page without it, possibly with the confirmation barcode number?

Answer (score 3):

The first step would be to get the application id, which you can do through the State Department's Electronic Application Center tool to [Retrieve an Application ID](https://ceac.state.gov/GENNIV/Help/Content/Retrieve%20an%20Application%20ID.htm).

When you complete that, it should take you to the last page you completed. If that is not the confirmation page print function, then go to the [Consular Electronic Application Center](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/) and select the Embassy/Consulate at which you applied (Barbados). Select *Option C-Retrieve Application* and, with your application ID number, you can view and print your confirmation page.